# In python, drawing a list of line segments given their indices

Tags: python, matplotlib

Given a list of vertices, and a list of line segments (indices which refer to the vertices of a segment), what's the best way of drawing all the lines segments where they may not form a continuous line?

I can do it this way, but it's obviously clunky; is there a better way?

```
vertices=[[0,0],[1,1],[1,2],[4,1]]
segs=[[0,1],[0,2],[2,3]] 

for seg in segs:
    x = vertices[seg[0]][0], vertices[seg[1]][0]
    y = vertices[seg[0]][1], vertices[seg[1]][1]
    plot(x, y, 'k')
```

[image: This is what I get]

@CactusWoman gives a way that works. This is the full code.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.collections
import matplotlib.pyplot

vertices=[[0,0],[1,1],[1,2],[4,1]]
segs=[[0,1],[0,2],[2,3]] 

lines = [[tuple(vertices[j]) for j in i]for i in segs]
lc = matplotlib.collections.LineCollection(lines)

fig, ax = matplotlib.pyplot.subplots()
ax.add_collection(lc)
matplotlib.pyplot.xlim([0,4])
matplotlib.pyplot.ylim([0,2])
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work because there are only three vertices, but the last segment references a fourth vertex. Are the values in `segs` suppose to reference vertices?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. My actual data is a list of floats with many digits. Fixed. And I gave the mistaken impression that there were the same number of segments as vertices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want `lineCollection` for this. Give it a list of lists of tuples, where each tuple is a vertex and each list contains all vertices of a segment.

```
lines = [[tuple(vertices[j]) for j in i]for i in segs]

lc = matplotlib.collections.LineCollection(lines)
```

Then use `add_collection` to add it to your axes.

Comment: @pheon Apologies, I fixed the code (I had the tuple call in the wrong place). It should work now. Using a line collection is much faster than plotting individual lines if you have a lot of lines, although it doesn't matter much if your number of lines is small.

Comment: Do you need to call `tuple`? That's just converting a 2-element list into a 2-element tuple and doesn't seem strictly necessary (but I can't test on this comp).

Comment: @o_o Yes, it would seem that `LineCollection` requires a list of lists of tuples.

Comment: I updated the code and am still missing the last line.

Comment: @pheon Works fine for me, it plots all three lines. Are you sure your axes are in the correct range?

Comment: Ah. I didn't realize that add_collection does not automatically adjust the axes range like plot. I accepted your answer and put my full code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a more Pythonic solution:

```
for v1,v2 in segs:
    x,y = zip(vertices[v1],vertices[v2])
    plot(x,y,'k')
```

Assuming that I understand what you're trying to do. Since they are not necessarily continuous, I think you're going to have to iterate over `segs` and plot them individually no matter what.

Comment: This works and saves one line. It may be the best solution, but CactusWoman's solution looks interesting, if it would work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is much better but you could zip your vertices and segs and loop over them like so.

```
vertices=[[0,0],[0,1],[3,2]]
segs=[[0,1],[0,2],[2,3]]

for v,s in zip(vertices, segs):
    x = v[0], s[0]
    y = v[1], s[1]
    plot(x,y,'k')
```

I'm not sure I totally understand your code but you will get an error since you are trying to access an index that doesn't exist. This is just a 1:1 relationship. index `x` vertices to index `x` segs